# React, redux, redux observable: Promise resolve type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-observable

I am trying to define the type of a a promise's resolve.
The following is the portion of the code or if you want to look it up on github: https://github.com/Electra-project/Electra-Desktop/blob/master/src/app/header/epics.ts

```
export function getStakingInfo(action$: ActionsObservable<HeaderActions>, store: any): any {
  return action$.ofType(ActionNames.GET_STAKING_INFO)
    .map(() => store.getState().electra.electraJs) // get electraJs object from the store
    .filter((electraJs: any) => electraJs) // check if electraJs exists
    .map(async (electraJs: any) => electraJs.wallet.getStakingInfo())
    .switchMap(async (promise: Promise<WalletStakingInfo>) => new Promise((resolve) => {
      promise
        .then((data: WalletStakingInfo) => {
          resolve({
            payload: {
              ...data
            },
            type: ActionNames.GET_STAKING_INFO_SUCCESS
          })
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          resolve({
            type: ActionNames.GET_STAKING_INFO_FAIL
          })
        })
    }))
    .catch((err: any) =>
      Observable.of({
        type: ActionNames.GET_STAKING_INFO_FAIL
      }))
}
```

I am getting an error that says that `resolve` inside the portion of the above code  is not type defined `new Promise((resolve) => {`. however I am unsure of the type of resolve.

Anybody can guide me as to what the type of resolve should be here?

Answer (score 0):

You can just define your own type like this for example:

```
type Resolve = (action: { payload?: WalletStakingInfo; type: ActionNames; }) => void;

export function getStakingInfo(action$: ActionsObservable<HeaderActions>, store: any): any {
    return action$.ofType(ActionNames.GET_STAKING_INFO)
        .map(() => store.getState().electra.electraJs) // get electraJs object from the store
        .filter((electraJs: any) => electraJs) // check if electraJs exists
        .map(async (electraJs: any) => electraJs.wallet.getStakingInfo())
        .switchMap(async (promise: Promise<WalletStakingInfo>) => new Promise((resolve: Resolve) => {
            promise
                .then((data: WalletStakingInfo) => {
                    resolve({
                        payload: {
                            ...data
                        },
                        type: ActionNames.GET_STAKING_INFO_SUCCESS
                    })
                })
                .catch((err: any) => {
                    resolve({
                        type: ActionNames.GET_STAKING_INFO_FAIL
                    })
                })
        }))
        .catch((err: any) =>
            Observable.of({
                type: ActionNames.GET_STAKING_INFO_FAIL
            }))
}
```

Comment: can you explain what kind of a type is Resolve? I have not seen a type with () in it.

Comment: `Resolve` in my example above is just a function type. It might be clearer without the arguments e.g. `type F = () => number;` describes a function type that takes no arguments and returns a number. This could then be used like this: `const f: F = () => 0;`.